# Can I set different timezone offset for every key when using tumbling Windows in flink?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

as the example in flink doc:

```
input
.keyBy(<key selector>)
.window(TumblingEventTimeWindows.of(Time.days(1), Time.hours(-8)))
.<windowed transformation>(<window function>);
```

I want to set different offset for every key, because it has different timezone.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement a custom `WindowAssigner` that takes the timezone into account when assigning records to windows. If you want to go that route, you might want to fork the `TumblingEventTimeWindows` assigner and extend it with custom logic to handle timezones.

You can also create windows per timezone with this approach.

Answer (score 1):

If I've understood correctly, it seems like you should use a map to transform all the timestamps into UTC. You'll want do that before your timestamp extractor / watermark generator.

In other words, shift the timestamps around so you don't need to vary the offset by key.